# Find a word with strike-through in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, converters, ghostscript, strikethrough

Is there a programmatic way to find a specific word containing a strike-through in a PDF file?

For example: <strike>test</strike>

I've tried converting the PDF to txt using the following (ghostscript) command:

```
gswin64.exe -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o output.txt "C:\docs\Letter.pdf"
```

But the word 'test' just appears as normal in output.txt

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: strikethrough is just formatting applied to the text. it doesn't modify the text, it just changes how it's DISPLAYED. that means you can't just look for "strikethrough text", you need to look for styling commands that make strikethrough occur, then get any text affected by that styling command.

Comment: I see, thanks Marc. I've tried different outputs provided by ghostscript, namely ps2write, eps2write, pxlmono, but none seemed to help

Comment: Perhaps I should convert the PDF to HTML and look for the strike-through there...

Comment: that'd only help if the converter's smart enough to apply a `text-decoration:strike` or whatever. maybe the PDF was built by drawing a graphical line through the text, in which case you won't see any strikethrough "text", because it's plain regular text with a picture of a line on top

Comment: We'd have to see the PDF in question to be certain, but there are two possibilities. Firstly that the font itself is a strike-through font, in this case there's simply no way to detect it. Secondly that the text is simply text with a line on top. There is no 'attribute' (or metadata) that describes text in that way in PDF. Don't count on converting it to HTML telling you anything either, as Marc B says, that will only help if the strike-through can be spotted as such, which it 'probably' can't. But if you put the file somewhere public and post a URL I'll look at it and tell you.

Comment: Thanks Ken, the PDF is a Microsoft Word file that has been converted to PDF using a virtual print called PDFCreator. I'll post a sample when I get time on Monday